# How to fix StatusCode: 500 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent. Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, razor, blazor

I am using Blazor WebAssembly .Net 8. I am getting the following error when using authentication
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent, Headers:
{
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2024 10:27:57 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/json
}   object

I don't know whats going wrong!

This is my TokenRequest Model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsHWl.png)

This is my login page;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ0jt.png)

This is the code excecuted when sign in button is clicked;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/628TE.png)

the _tokenRequest is populated as below;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORhTr.png)

Then it hits my Login Function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLUR6.png)

It then Hits my LoginAsync Function but just bombs out when it hits the FindByEmailAsync. The model.Email is populated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G9WM.png)

This is the response in get in DevTools
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vESMX.png)

I have spent the last couple of days going through most of the questions already posted and trying them, but to no avail

Comment: An internal server error just means that you have an unhandled exception in your server code somewhere. If you are running the app locally you should be able to see a stack trace in your console, or you could even step through the code until you find the error.

Comment: I have stepped through my code... and everything is fine until I come to the          
await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
The _userManager is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity framework, which I cannot Debug

Comment: Sounds like you've found where the problem lies. Also, you I presume you've just posted screenshots of your code - you should post any relevant code directly in the question. This is to make the question readable, and to help others find the question and any solution(s) that get posted.

Comment: Instead of adding code as images add code inline with the question. This helps us help you answer the question quicker.